# The lower() function on international characters in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a standard postgresql server from a new and an old ubuntu repository.

The first is postgresql server 8.3.12. Here the lower() function works correctly on the Danish letter 'Æ'

```
go=#  select lower('Æ');
 lower
-------
 æ
(1 row)
```

Now on postgres 9.1.9 the function doesn't work (it returns the same uppercase letter)

```
go=# select lower('Æ');
 lower
-------
Æ
(1 row)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to change this behavior?

(my real problem is that ilike doesn't work on Danish characters either, but I thought the above example would make the problem more clear)

Comment: Are you sure you haven't missed something, it works on sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1253, version 9.1.9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your database was probably created with a different locale.

Check `\l+` in `psql` on the old and new versions. They'll have different locale settings.

Other possibilities are different operating systems/versions. PostgreSQL uses libc's locale rules, and some platforms (notably Mac OS X) have a bit of a ... special ... libc.

On 9.1.9 with an `en_AU.UTF-8` database running on Fedora 19 I get:

```
regress=> select lower('Æ');
 lower 
-------
 æ
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yes, it was the locale. I ended up changing the LANG environment variable from en_DK.UTF-8 to da_DK.UTF-8. Uninstalling postgresql, installing it again and restoring the dump from from postgresql 8.3. That made it work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be that the PostgreSQL cluster was created by the system (Ubuntu 12.04) upon installation, and had taken C as the lc_ctype, and ASCII as the encoding, instead of inheriting from the locale, which was en_DK.UTF8. After doing a pg_dropcluster and a pg_createcluster, the correct locale and encoding was used, and everything started working correctly.

Comment: If you mean `SQL_ASCII`, it is pure evil. Be glad you caught that and fixed it.