# Postgres make lower work for Swedish language (other Nordic too)

Tags: postgresql, lowercase

When I'm running query:

select lower('Ågab') from account limit 1;

on my postgres database the result looks like this:

Ågab

How to make it to look like:

ågab

This is Swedish, but in the same database I have also Danish and Norwegian names.

Comment: For me ```select lower('Ågab');``` returns ```ågab```

Comment: Just check it on other database. On test database it works fine, but it doesn't on production.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The lower() function on international characters in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507589/the-lower-function-on-international-characters-in-postgresql)

Comment: Yes it looks like it's an encoding problem. Is there a way to convert it to UTF8 and run lower on it? I was trying to select lower(convert_to('Ågab', 'UTF8')); but it return an error: "function lower(bytea) does not exist" and select lower(convert_to('Ågab', 'UTF8')::varchar); returns: \xc385676162 I'm looking for such solution because changing encoding on my database won't be painless task.

Comment: Make sure all your databases are created with UTF8 encoding,