# Why does postgres `lower()` not lowercase È in my function

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, plpgsql, case-sensitive

Look at this snapshot:

[image]

Might any explain to me what's going on?

In other words:
I have this function

```
create or replace function primera_majuscula(str name) returns name as $$
    begin
        return upper(substring(str from 1 for 1)) || lower(substring(str from 2));
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

It receives a name typed parameter, and returns a name typed value as well. Its name is "primera_majuscula()" that means "first_capital_letter()", and it returns the input parameter with its first letter in uppercase and the others in lower case. The way it does so is by using the substring function and concatenating the first letter once uppered with the others after lowered.

Moreover, as you can see in the snapshot, if I ask for the body of the function directly on the prompt, it works right. But not in the case when I ask for the function.

Can someone explain that? Is it really a bug?

I tried restarting the server, since it does not commit the mistake in the development installation. Just in the production one. But nothing.

---

ADDED TEXT

This question is similar to the one published in

[The lower() function on international characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507589/the-lower-function-on-international-characters-in-postgresql).

And certainly, my Collate and Ctype are different between my development server (where the problem does not appear) and the production one (where the problem raised).

In the development server I have this:
[image]

While in the production one, this:
[image]

That could explain the different behaviors.

So, ahead I will only focus on the production one:

In contrast with the problem posted by user2728690, I had this working right:

[image]

Anyway, finally, I changed the types used in the function. I put text instead of names.

```
create or replace function primera_majuscula(str text) returns text as $$
    begin
        return upper(substring(str from 1 for 1)) || lower(substring(str from 2));
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

And it worked.

Honestly, I have no time to reinstall the cluster.

Comment: What's your databases charset?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe , I think this question is not a dublicate of [the-lower-function-on-international-characters-in-postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507589/the-lower-function-on-international-characters-in-postgresql) because it is about the result of lower() on the same database. In essence it is about why types "name" and "text" are treated differently.

Comment: change the function signature from `str name` to `str text` (and the output type). The type `name` is an internal PG type

Comment: Yes JGH, that's what solved the problem. Thank you.