# PosgreSQL not considering UNICODE upper / lower replacements from accented, etc. characters

Tags: postgresql, unicode, encoding, locale

This may be very similar to [The lower() function on international characters in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507589/the-lower-function-on-international-characters-in-postgresql) but not the same, and since we aren't supposed to pile on questions to an existing one, here goes.

I always use the simplest UNICODE locale in my PgSQL setups:

```
mydb => \l+
                                                               List of databases
    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description
------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 mydb       | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =Tc/postgres         +| 238 GB  | pg_default |
            |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres+|         |            |
            |          |          |         |       | agent=c/postgres     +|         |            |
            |          |          |         |       | developer=C/postgres  |         |            |
 postgres   | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     |                       | 7913 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 template0  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +| 7753 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
            |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
 template1  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +| 7753 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
            |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            |
 tutorial   | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     |                       | 7753 kB | pg_default |
(5 rows)
```

and I discovered that upper/lower functions don't get it:

```
mydb =>  select upper('árvore ação');
    upper
-------------
 áRVORE AçãO
(1 row)
```

There is a similar issue with non latin letters not being considered letters in the \w regex, but I think that is POSIX related.

What CTYPE or LOCALE should I use? I do not want to be specific to any language because my database processes data from all languages. It is not a language specific matter that upper of 'árvore ação αβγ' is 'ÁRVORE AÇÃO ΑΒΓ'.

Comment: Not sure why you would think the `ctype` of `C` would know anything about the casing of multiple languages.

Comment: Works fine for me: ÁRVORE AÇÃO

Comment: @FrankHeikens so what is your \l+ say? Because obviously it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver UNICODE itself has the case folding map, so I don't even get why any of this complication should be required if I select UTF-8 for the encoding?

Comment: UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8, my default for all languages, including Portuguese

Comment: @GuntherSchadow.  From here [Locale](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html): *LC_CTYPE  Character classification (What is a letter? Its upper-case equivalent?)*

Comment: @GuntherSchadow you are using the C locale which is ASCII. All no ASCII characters are being left as is, and ASCII characters are being cased. That is to be expected.

Comment: As to your other question, what the appropriate locale would be depends on whether you are using libc locales or whether your install of postgresql has ICU support enabled. It sounds like you need language insensitive operations. For ICU, you could use `und-x-icu`, this would use CLDR's root locale, although I suspect you might get by with an English Unicode locale with a libc locale.